# Keep control over macOS sound when connecting stereo via MiniDP/HDMI

Tags: macos, mac, audio, hdmi, mini-displayport

When I connect my MacBook to my old stereo via Mini-Display-Port -> HDMI -> HDMI-Sound-Splitter -> Jack cable -> Stereo, I can't control the Mac-volume anymore because it is disabled. So I just can use the buttons on the stereo to control the sound.

How is it possible to regain the control over the Mac-volume? I couldn't find anything except for a workaround with the program soundflower + soundflowerbed but they stop working spontaneously, so are not very reliable.
I'm using macOS High Sierra.

Comment: software recs don't make good answers here, but [Audio Hijack](https://rogueamoeba.com/audiohijack/) will do that & more [set it on a timer from 00:01 to 23:59 & it will launch with the Mac]. It is what Soundflower never was. They also do a more 'pro' structure called Loopback, but more expensive & less flexible for that particular need. see https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/271164/split-input-channels-using-soundflower-and-aulab/271194#271194 & https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/203004/nice-audio-mixer-repeater/203009#203009 for examples, though none quite what you asked for.

Comment: Yeah Audio Hijack seems pretty nice, but it can't give me the control over the volume, so that I can control it with the volume buttons on the keyboard. It's not installing a virtual device or something. I just don't understand why such a basic feature is not onboard from Apple ...

Answer (score 0):

**The original answer is [Here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/336750/how-do-i-control-macbook-volume-when-a-dp-display-is-connected/366330?noredirect=1#comment531093_366330)!**

What finally works very well for free is:

https://eqmac.app/

---

Old Answer:

An app that is very useful in this case is [Sound Control](https://staticz.com/soundcontrol/). Even with the trial it is possible to control the sound when the Mac is connected to the stereo. So very good 0$ solution.

**Edit:** On MacOS Mojave Sound Control is not working anymore for my scenario.